# WERR_ACCESS_DENIED error despite all services running

Tags: windows, windows-service, rpc

I am trying to list all `rpc` commands from an `Ubuntu` machine on a `Win 10 Pro` machine:

```
net rpc service list -I <ip> -U username
```

Getting the following error:

> Failed to open Service Control Manager. [WERR_ACCESS_DENIED]

All the following services are running on the target (Windows) host however:

> Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
>
> Computer Browser
>
> Server
>
> Remote Registry
>
> Windows Management Instrumentation
>
> Netlogon
>
> Remote Desktop Services
>
> Windows Remote Management (WS-Management)

File / Printer sharing is enabled also.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to allow these kind of remote calls in the UAC too.

In the PowerShell (as Administrator):

`reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`

More information can be found here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/942817/how-to-change-the-remote-uac-localaccounttokenfilterpolicy-registry-se